# Error when printing excel tab to PDF using PDF Factory Pro

Tags: excel

Ok, I have a vb.net (Visual Studio 2008) program that opens an excel file from a database, and goes through each tab, and prints the tab to a PDF using PDF Factory Pro.  When the excel file is smaller, less than 200 tabs, it works flawlessly to go through all tabs, each one printing to a PDF, and then when done, closing everything out, and opening another excel file and doing the same thing.  Now, my problem occurs when the file has more than 300 tabs in it.  The first file will run through fine and create all the PDFs, but when I try and run it again, opening another excel file with over 300 tabs, part way through I'm getting an error.  It looks like it's a PDF error, but when I try to close it out, it says, HRESULT: 0x800A03EC.  I have tried EVERYTHING and can not get it to work.  The program does not save off the excel file...it just opens it, and goes through tab by tab, each tab printing to PDF.  The PDF is then saved back to the database where the excel file was downloaded from.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Excel has the native ability to save as a PDF. You don't need any third party software as far as I know. Just select all the sheets and do a save type as a PDF

This macro should work fine. Just input your own file location:

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
    Sheets.Select
    Sheet1.Activate
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "\\bergstein\User Documents$\jbelman\My Documents\test.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Good Luck.